# Relationship between clock rate and speed

Tags: special-relativity, time, observers, time-dilation

Let's consider example:

The propagation of light from the middle of a moving train to its left and right ends. From the point of view of a train passenger, the light will reach the right and left ends of the train at the same time, from the point of view of an outside observer - at different times.

Time of motion from the point of view of an outside observer:

$$t_1 = \frac{L}{(c-V)}$$

$L$ - half train length, $c$ - speed of light, $V$ - speed of train

Time of propagation of light from the point of view of a train passenger:

$$t_2 = \frac{L}{c}$$

Now, let we have "object" instead of train which moves with very large speed $$V=\frac{c}{2}$$
$t_1$ and $t_2$:

$$t_1 = \frac{L}{(c-c/2)} = \frac{2L}{c}$$
$$t_2 = \frac{L}{c}$$

Then $$t_1 = 2t_2$$

Is it right that clock rate from the point of view of an object observer depends on speed of object $V=c/2$? And thus clock of an object observer will tick twice as slow than clock of outside observer because speed of object is half of speed of light. Is it true?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No- effects in SR are not directly related to the ratio of the speed involved to the speed of light. The first mistake you have made is to overlook the fact that, in the frame of the track, the time required for the light to reach the front of the train will be greater than the time required for the light to reach the rear of the train. I suggest that you reconsider the rest of your reasoning after taking what I have just said into account.